# How do I force a column-break in a multi-column page?

Tags: page-breaking, multicol

I want to display my article's abstract and table of contents side-by-side, to save space. I'm using the `multicol` package, but it tries to keep each column the same height, and I can't figure out how to force it to move content into the second column.

Here's a mockup; I'm just padding out the abstract to show what it should look like. The layout is perfect, I just want a way to do this properly:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section*{Abstract}

\lipsum[1-2]

a % padding to make the first column run to
  % end of page
a

a

a

a

a

a

a

a

a

a

a

a

\tableofcontents
\end{multicols}
```

And here's what it looks like, rendered (perfect except for the padding lines):

[image: Result]

Comment: I fixed the image in your post. Please only use the official interface to upload images (e.g. CTRL+G), otherwise they might break after a while.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

- Put `\vfill\null` after the last line to break.
- And then put `\columnbreak` after `\vfill\null`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\title{Introduction to \LaTeX}
\author{xport}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Abstract}
\lipsum[1-2]
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
%\vfill\null
%\columnbreak
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Counter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Box}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Parbox}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Rule}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can move the `\maketitle` to any line before `\begin{multicols}` (of course after `\begin{document}`) to match your preference.

Comment: I am getting a compilation error for using `\columnbreak`, but placing only `\vfill` after the last line before the column break seems to work just fine.

Comment: Due to a change in multicols, you should use \vspace*{\fill} or \vfill\null instead of \vfill.

Comment: What's the purpose of `\null`?

Answer (score 55):

If you are not using the `multicols` package you can insert a column break by adding the following:

```
\vfill\eject
```

Comment: ...or issue a `\vfill\break`.

Comment: In my specific case, just doing `\vfill`resulted in desired layout

Answer (score 33):

The command, appropriately enough, is `\columnbreak`.

If you want to turn off columns being forced to equal height, use the starred version `\begin{multicols*}{2}`.

Comment: I think we need `\vfill` before `\columnbreak`.

Comment: You changed your code after I posted, and it was hard to tell what needed to be done with the old code. You only need `\vfill` if you want to avoid rubber spacing filling in the extra space. You can turn that off globally with `\raggedcolumns` -- I'd prefer that to `\vfill`.

Comment: @frabjous from all the responses here `\raggedcolumns` was the one finally solving this problem I've been having for months. Too bad I'm usually too impatient to read through all the comments on all the replies...

Comment: Is there a way to force new column for new chapters ?

Comment: @CasperYC I'm sure there is, but the mystery isn't how you do it, it's how you got it not to do it in the first place, as in most document classes that would already be default behavior. Consider posting a new question with some minimal code that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `paracol` package where you can use `\switchcolumn` to break pages.