# How do I force a column-break in a two-column document?

Tags: page-breaking, two-column

Similar to *[How do I force a column-break in a multi-column page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/how-do-i-force-a-column-break-in-a-multi-column-page)* I want to force a column-break in a two-column document.

```
\columnbreak
```

seems to be undefined without the `multicol` package.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

use `\newpage` instead. A `twocolumn` document is for TeX the same as two half pages side by side

Comment: You may need to precede it with a \\ Otherwise the first line after the \newpage is still on the previous page. (happened to me)

Answer (score 48):

Just use `\newpage`. And use `\clearpage` for a new page.

Comment: Orwell would be proud.

Comment: @AlecJacobson: For the uneducated (but intrigued) among us: Can you elaborate/explain?

Comment: @Make42 E was probably referring to the similarity to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10763/128553 which was posted four minutes earlier. However, https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2674/leo-liu might have started to write this answer before user2478 published https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10763/128553, hence the implied accusal might be insubstantial. In addition, this answer provides additional useful information.

Comment: @CampanIgnis: Now, that I am reading this again: I think that might not be it. Or what would you writing it again have anything to do with Orwell? I think, Alex means that one does not use "newpage" to get a new page, but clearpage to get a new page. This sound very counterintuitive and "clearpage" for a new page is also unexpected: one might think that it removes a page, but you actually get a new page... The reference to Orwell is due to the "new speak" in Orwell's "big brother" (if I recall correctly), which is a "language" which distorts (on purpose) the meaning of words to subdue people.

Comment: @Make42 I thought of Orwell's book "nineteen eighty-four" and one institution spying on someone which consequently allows to steal ideas. \clearpage (and \cleardoublepage) for a new page are not counterintuitive as it is a well known command which is described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45619/128553 and elsewhere. Every LaTeX instruction book needs to include this command. But I agree that a new command \clearcolumn or \newcolumn like in would be more intuitive than \newpage here. I did not thought about the newspeak aspect. Btw, Orwell should not be reduced to "nineteen eighty-four".

Comment: @CampanIgnis You're right, Orwell should not be reduced to 1984. So, O'Brien would be proud.