# splitbib and table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, page-breaking, subdividing, splitbib

I use the [`splitbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/splitbib) package to create two categories: primary literature and secondary literature. But I want to add in the table of contents an entry for each category, as if they are subsections or something like that. Moreover, I want also to split each category but the first in a new page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[export]{splitbib}

\begin{category}{Primary Literature}
  \SBentries{samplea}
\end{category}

\begin{category}{Secondary Literature}
  \SBentries{sampleb}
\end{category}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

  \bibitem[Sample, A]{samplea} Sample A.

  \bibitem[Sample, B]{sampleb} Sample B.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

and I want to add in the table of contents, like a subsection, an entry for the category Primary Literature and Secondary Literature, and to split the second category (and third, fourth and so on) in a separated page.

How can be this achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a solution similar to that in [Forcing new categories in splitbib to start on new pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70118/forcing-new-categories-in-splitbib-to-start-on-new-pages): Define a new style that resembles the default style `bar` but adds the appropriate `\addcontentsline` macro. (Simply adding `\addcontentsline` immediately before the `thebibliography` environment is likely to produce wrong page references in the ToC.) Note that `splitbib` doesn't seem to forbid page breaks between a subbibliography heading and the first entry.

EDIT: Added automatic page break before any but the first subbibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[export]{splitbib}

\newif\ifafterfirstsubbib
\afterfirstsubbibfalse

\makeatletter
\def\NMSB@styletocentrybar#1#2{%
  \ifafterfirstsubbib% NEW
    \clearpage% NEW
  \else% NEW
    \afterfirstsubbibtrue% NEW
  \fi% NEW
  \hskip-\leftmargin%
  \vbox{%
    \medskip\par
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}% NEW
    \vrule height \SBabovesepwidth depth 0pt width \textwidth
    \vskip.3\baselineskip\par\noindent
    {\null\hfill
      \csname SB\NMSB@level font\endcsname{#1#2}%
      \hfill\null}%
    \vskip-.4\baselineskip\par\noindent
    \vrule height \SBbelowsepwidth depth 0pt width \textwidth}}
\makeatother

\SBtitlestyle{tocentrybar}

\begin{category}{Primary Literature}
  \SBentries{samplea}
\end{category}

\begin{category}{Secondary Literature}
  \SBentries{sampleb}
\end{category}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

  \bibitem[Sample, A]{samplea} Sample A.

  \bibitem[Sample, B]{sampleb} Sample B.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70118/forcing-new-categories-in-splitbib-to-start-on-new-pages is that a new page for each category is created, included the first category (and thus, the "References" title keeps alone in a separate page).

Comment: @Peregring-lk Just try out my present answer -- first as-is, then remove the line  starting with `\textheight=200pt`.

Comment: Perhaps, to improve efficiency, you could add an else statement to step the counter only one time, because thereafter isn't important the value of the counter.

Comment: I don't know the command \newif :) I tried with counters and a classical if/else but the yours is far better elegant.