# Put figures before the specified page

Tags: graphics

In some conferences in CS field such as KDD, last one or two page(s) must be only for bibliography. So, images should not be put on those pages.

Is it possible to force figures insert before specified pages? For example, in KDD, 10th pages is only for bib. So, I'd like to put all figures before page 9.

I know [how](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text) to put images on (exactly) specified point but would like to know put images *before* the specific page.

Comment: A `\clearpage` command should help. [See here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45609/is-it-wrong-to-use-clearpage-instead-of-newpage/45619#45619)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the reference section does not start a new page (then `\clearpage` helps as suggested by JMP in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301177/put-figures-before-the-specified-page#comment729645_301177)), then package `placeins` provides a command `\FloatBarrier`. It forbids floats to float past this point.

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{document}
...
\FloatBarrier
% References
...
\end{document}
```