# Force new page in a two-column article

Tags: page-breaking, two-column

In a two-column article, `\newpage` goes to the start of the next column, which might be on the same page. How can I force moving to an entirely new page?

I tried:

```
\newpage 
~
\newpage
```

This works in the left column, but in the right column it jumps to the right column of the next page. I am looking for a solution that always jumps to the left column of the new page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it wrong to use \clearpage instead of \newpage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45609/is-it-wrong-to-use-clearpage-instead-of-newpage) See, in particular, [Frank Mittelbach's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45619/5001) to that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `\clearpage`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\clearpage  % <---
\lipsum[4-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, thanks!