# How to disable \newpage

Tags: macros, page-breaking

I would like to disable the command `\newpage`.

I did the following but it does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\newpage}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\newpage
\item C
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: well.... it works, `\newpage` is disabled so in particular the `\newpage` that is in`\end{document}` doesn't happen and no page is shipped out. beware what you ask for.

Comment: you probably just want to do the redefinition in some group eg inside the itemize in this example.

Comment: Why? isn't it simpler and safer not use it?

Comment: @Zarko: thank you!!!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle A possible workout would be to redefine `\newpage` to its initial value before \end{document}. Could you help me to achieve that?
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to acccomplish?

Comment: I want to temporarily disable all the `\newpage` used in a document.

Comment: @Colas note `\newpage` is used in `\clearpage` and as such is vital for the float mechanism, if you disable it and use figures or tables they are likely to get lost or the document not terminate

Comment: A `Replace all` editor command would have been easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you include the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\orignewpage\newpage 
    \renewcommand\newpage{}
    \patchcmd{\clearpage}{\newpage}{\orignewpage}{}{}}
```

That way, the code chunk

```
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\newpage
\item C
\end{itemize}
```

is assured not to generate a page break between items B and C.

Observe that it's *very necessary* to patch `\clearpage`, since `\clearpage` contains a `\newpage` directive internally and because `\clearpage` is used by quite a few LaTeX macros, including the `\enddocument` macro that's run when `\end{document}` is encountered. For more on the subject of `\newpage` vs. `\clearpage`, see the posting [Is it wrong to use \clearpage instead of \newpage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45609/5001) (shameless self-citation alert!)

(If other LaTeX macros contain a `\newpage` directive internally, those macros would need to be patched as well. One such macro, which is defined by the LaTeX kernel, is `\cleardoublepage`. Fortunately (?) for you, `\cleardoublepage` doesn't get used by the `article` document class *unless* the options `\twoside` and `\openright` are both set.)

Comment: +1 for rescuing the float mechanism :-)