# Tabularray (longtblr) for wide tables in two column documents

Tags: tables, longtable, two-column, double-sided, tabularray

## Revised Question to Add Clarity

When trying to incorporate a wide (wider than `\columnwidth`), long table (`longtblr`) in a `twocolumn` document class like `article`, the table will spill onto the next column instead of the next page.  How can I overcome this?

Here's an MWE (adapting the `longtblr` example from Chapter 4 of the `tablurarray` package (v2023A)):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {A Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Table},
  entry = {Short Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
  note{a} = {It is the first footnote.},
  note{$\dag$} = {It is the second long long long long long long footnote.},
  remark{Note} = {Some general note. Some general note. Some general note.},
  remark{Source} = {Made up by myself. Made up by myself. Made up by myself.},
]{
  colspec = {lll},
  rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1,
  row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {brown9},
  row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7},
}
\hline
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
\hline
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta\TblrNote{a}       & Eta    \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa\TblrNote{$\dag$} & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Foot    & Foot  & Foot    \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Problem with wide, long tables]

## Original Question

I have a two column (or double column) template where I want to use longtblr for tables. I really like how tabularray (where longtblr is defined) works. It is simple, easy to use, and most of all, it looks quite nice (my subjective opinion). I used it for single column documents and also for two columnm documents with small tables. However, I don't quite get the hang of it for using it properly for wide tables which span accross two columns. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTblrTheme{TC}{%
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{Continued on next column/page}
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{font=\footnotesize\itshape, fg=black!80}
}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

    \begin{longtblr}[
    theme = TC,
    caption = {Long table caption.},
    label = {table:ips},
    ]{
        hlines, vlines,
        colspec = { X[l] X[2,l] X[3,l]},
        rowhead = 2,
        %   colsep = 3pt,
        row{even} = {gray9},
        row{1} = {blue!30},
        row{2} = {font=\small\bfseries, c}
    }
    \SetCell[c=3]{c}        A nice Table
    &               &               \\
    Part A  &   Part B      &   Part C      \\
    Hmmm    & This is not & what I want \\
    Hmmm    & This is not & what I want \\
    Hmmm    & This is not & what I want \\
    Hmmm    & This is not & what I want \\
    Hmmm    & This is not & what I want \\
    Hmmm    & This is not & what I want \\
    Hmmm    & This is not & what I want \\
    Hmmm    & This is not & what I want \\
    Hmmm    & This is not & what I want \\
    Hmmm    & This is not & what I want \\
\end{longtblr}
\lipsum[3-4]

\begin{table*}
\begin{longtblr}[
    theme = TC,
    caption = {Long table caption.},
    label = {table:ips},
    ]{
        hlines, vlines,
        colspec = { X[l] X[2,l] X[3,l]},
        rowhead = 2,
        %   colsep = 3pt,
        row{even} = {gray9},
        row{1} = {blue!30},
        row{2} = {font=\small\bfseries, c}
    }
    \SetCell[c=3]{c}        A nice Table
    &               &               \\
    Part A  &   Part B      &   Part C      \\
    With a table* around longtblr environment    & it seems to work partially & but then it duplicates the table \\
    With a table* around longtblr environment    & it seems to work partially & but then it duplicates the table \\

\end{longtblr}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[5-12]


\end{document}
```

Which produces this:
[image: Desired Table Explanation]

**My Question:** How can I make this table span two columns? Thank you very much.

If this is not possible, how can I replicate a similar table with another package that works? (Notice the alternating color between rows)

EDIT: Added a minimal example. Thanks to Zarko.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem!

Comment: I think you should use a `table*` environment and put a regular `tblr` in it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried what you suggested and put a table* around it. However, it duplicates my table (I think it gets duplicated because it would go over the end of a column but I am not sure)

Comment: Can I conclude, that you actually not need long table since it can be fit on one page? BTW, it will be nice, that you will mentioned that code is taken from my answer ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure guessing what you after:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewTblrTheme{TC}{%
    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{Continued on next column/page}
       \SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{font=\footnotesize\itshape, fg=black!80}
                  }
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{longtblr}[
  theme = TC,
caption = {Long table caption.},
label = {table:ips},
                ]{
  hlines, vlines,
  colspec = { X[l] X[2,l] X[3,l]},
  rowhead = 2,
%   colsep = 3pt,
row{even} = {gray9},
   row{1} = {blue!30},
   row{2} = {font=\small\bfseries, c}
                }
\SetCell[c=3]{c}        A nice Table
        &               &               \\
Part A  &   Part B      &   Part C      \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
\end{longtblr}

\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
It is still unclear what is your problem and how big is your table. From edited question one can conclude, that you not need a long table but you like that it span two columns. Am I right?

If this is the case, than try the following:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

    \begin{table*}[t]
    \caption{Long table caption.}
    \label{table:ips}
\begin{tblr}{
  hlines, vlines,
  colspec = { X[l] X[2,l] X[3,l] },
  rowhead = 2,
row{even} = {gray9},
   row{1} = {blue!30},
   row{2} = {font=\small\bfseries, c}
            }
\SetCell[c=3]{c}        A nice Table
        &               &               \\
Part A  &   Part B      &   Part C      \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
Hmmm    & This is not   & how I want it \\
It is   & not clear     & what you want \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum[6-12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this example! I changed it a bit and used it above for a minimal working example. However, this is not how I want the table., The table should span across the two columns (see updated image in question)

Comment: @CaptainGouLash, in accordance with the site policy, consider to award answer by voting it (by clicking on up-triangle at top left side of answer or even to accept it (by clicking on the check mark at the same place). as I see, so far you not accept any of received answers on your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, in my specific case it should be fine to use tblr instead of longtblr. But once the the table does not fit to the page anymore, it gets somehow duplicated (see in my question the orange marked table is actually duplicated). Is there a way to have the table span over two columns AND have it longer than a page?
You can replicate it with your last answer by a) adding more rows (content) to the table and b) change tblr to longtblr

Comment: Long tables had not to be enclosed in  `table` float. You need to clarify (in question) what is your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `multicol` package and put two column text inside `multicols` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Table Caption},
  label = {table:ips},
]{
  hlines, vlines,
  colspec = {X[l]X[2,l]X[3,l]},
  rowhead = 2,
  row{even} = {gray9},
  row{1} = {blue8},
  cell{1}{1} = {c=3}{c},
}
  A Nice Table &          &      \\
  Part A       & Part B & Part C \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
  Alpha        & Beta   & Gamma  \\
\end{longtblr}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `tabularray` package defines the `\TblrNewPage` macro to resolve to LaTeX's `\newpage` macro.  Because `\newpage`, in a two-column environment, advances to the next column regardless of whether that column is on the same or the next page, you can renew `\TblrNewPage` to use `\clearpage` instead.

```
\renewcommand{\TblrNewPage}{\clearpage}
```

[This StackExchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45619/263901) provides a good explanation of `\newpage` and `\clearpage`.  Note that if you subsequently need a narrow `tabularray` `longtblr`, then you will need to renew `\TblrNewPage` again to change it back to its default of `\newpage`.

Here's the updated MWE from the revised question above:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\TblrNewPage}{\clearpage}  %% <--- Added this line only
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {A Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Table},
  entry = {Short Caption},
  label = {tblr:test},
  note{a} = {It is the first footnote.},
  note{$\dag$} = {It is the second long long long long long long footnote.},
  remark{Note} = {Some general note. Some general note. Some general note.},
  remark{Source} = {Made up by myself. Made up by myself. Made up by myself.},
]{
  colspec = {lll},
  rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1,
  row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {brown9},
  row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7},
}
\hline
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
\hline
 Head    & Head  & Head    \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta\TblrNote{a}       & Eta    \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa\TblrNote{$\dag$} & Lambda \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Alpha Alpha Alpha Alpha   & Beta Beta Beta Beta  & Gamma Gamma Gamma Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
 Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
\hline
 Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
\hline
 Foot    & Foot  & Foot    \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

...and the resulting document:
[image: A wide, long table in a two-column environment that spans both columns]