# Latex document with figures only. How to place figures into sections?

Tags: floats

I need to create a latex document containing figures only. How can I organize them in sections? For example:

SECTION 1

"figure 1"

"figure 2"

"figure 3"

SECTION 2

"figure 4"

"figure 5"

"figure 6"

If I simply write this structure in the source I instead obtain a document like the following:

"figure 1"

SECTION 1

SECTION 2

"figure 2"

"figure 3"

"figure 4"

"figure 5"

"figure 6"

Comment: Try adding a `\clearpage` before every `\section`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45619/38080

Comment: `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`

Comment: A good reference: [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279/5001)