# Table appears after bibliography

Tags: tables, floats

I am relatively new to LaTeX and have been trying to implement a table into a paper I am working on. No matter what I do, however, I keep running into the problem of the table appearing after the bibliography despite coming first in the document. The following is the code:

```
\clearpage
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Sample APA table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
Mean & \ Standard Deviation \\
\midrule
Row 1 & Data 1  \\
Row 2 & Data 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\FloatBarrier
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I have tried using `\newpage` as well as changing the float placement of the table. No matter what, though, the table comes after the bibliography. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: as you used `[H]` either you should get an error that `H` is not defined (if you have not used the float package) or it will not float and not go to the end,

Comment: why is this tagged biblatex?

Comment: You can do a `\clearpage` before the bibliography.

Comment: See also [Is it wrong to use `\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45609/5001)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please complete your code snippet to a full and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Only this will make clear why your code does not result in the output you expect.