# Clear column on a double column document

Tags: floats, page-breaking, two-column

How do I clear a column in a double column document?
I have two floats, and I want each to occupy a different column.

`\clearpage` before the second float puts it on a new page, while `\pagebreak` does nothing (puts the two floats on the same column).

MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,english]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\newpage{}

\begin{figure}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Issue `\columnbreak`. However, you mention "floats" yet you're interested in a specific placement of them. Then I'd suggest *not* using floats. Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: ...if you're not using [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol), then see [How do I force a column-break in a two-column document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10760/5764)

Comment: For those who can't construct an MWE, here is a temporary file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnkgmx5bgcvef19/newfile1.tex

Comment: @ZoharLevi Who is your sentence referred to? BTW, I've added your MWE to the question...

Comment: Try loading the `float` package (`\usepackage{float}`) and then use `\begin{figure}[H]` instead of `\begin{figure}`

Comment: @Closers: the link provided doesn't answer this question...

Comment: Whom ever; although there weren't many people here when I wrote it. I added to the example above the float package and [H] and there's no change.

Comment: @ZoharLevi I suggest you to add in the question that the link provided as a solution (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10760/27635) doesn't answer your question, or it won't be reopened.

Comment: @karlkoeller 's solution works for me.  You need to provide a complete document when your problem occurs.

Comment: I added [H] only to the second figure. Now I added [H] to both, and it worked. But usually one should avoid using [H]. I think that some journals templates don't respect it, or maybe I don't really want the figure where it currently is, but only want to clear a column. Isn't there a cleaner solution?