# Title, abstract, and text beginning on same page

Tags: titles, abstract

What I want to do, is to create a document, which starts off with a title-minipage, abstract, and then start the main section.  Ideally, i would like to do it on the same page, kind of like a magazine article, rather than a bound book (which is how the latex titlepage appears.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlething}
     Formatting for title + author etc., perhaps even with
\end{titlething}
\maketitle 
\begin{abstract}
   abstract-text
\end{abstract}
\section{First bit}
If you want to ramp your text straight onto the title page, start the text at 
something that does not cause a page break, like a section.  Here's a handy 
place to introduce some of your woofy conventions, like quotes in equations.
\chapter{New Page}
A new chapter starts a new page.  
\end{document}
```

My idea was perhaps to set the title page in a minipage?  I'm trying to keep chapters in the document though, if that's a help, because i have a considerable collection in the 'report' style.

A minipage does not work.  \nopagebreak[4] does not work.

Actually 'notitlepage' option does work.  What is happening is that when you create a chapter, then that starts on a new page.  This is what most of my documents look like.

So if you really want to start text on the first page, consider using something like a section to introduce things before the first chapter.

Wendy is happy now.  :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does the `notitlepage` option help you?

Comment: @AndrewSwann notitlepage works.  What was happening was that the first text after 'abstract' was 'chapter', which was causing the page break.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  It does, i edited the example to show that it's really 'chapter' that is causing the problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that use of `titling` http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling  is a way to do it

[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{\begin{center}\Large\ttfamily}
\postauthor{\end{center}}
\predate{\par\large\centering}
\postdate{\par}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME and ID}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section*{First bit}
If you want to ramp your text straight onto the title page, start the text at 
something that does not cause a page break, like a section.  Here's a handy 
place to introduce some of your woofy conventions, like quotes in equations.
\chapter{New Page}
A new chapter starts a new page.  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want to have it look like an article, you should use an `article`. Like this, no hacking is needed. The command `\chapter` does not exist, but `\section` will give a title like "1 Chapter" anyway. If you want to get a report feeling for the next chapters (sections), you can just add a `\clearpage` behind your first chapter.

In your collection, you just have to replace all `\subsection` by `\subsubsection`, all `\section` by `\subsection` and finally all `\chapter` by `\section`. And then change the documentclass to `article`.

Looks like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\author{author}
\date{\today}
\title{title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    abstract-text
\end{abstract}
\section{First bit}
If you want to ramp your text straight onto the title page, start the text at 
something that does not cause a page break, like a section.  Here's a handy 
place to introduce some of your woofy conventions, like quotes in equations.
\newpage
\section{New Page}
A new chapter starts a new page.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, this fails if we use `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`.

Comment: @DanielSank what does fail exactly? Maybe see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10760/how-do-i-force-a-column-break-in-a-two-column-document

Comment: With the method in this answer, adding the `twocolumn` option put the abstract in the same part of the document as the text. In other words, the abstract appears just like a section.