# Start text on same page as title with one-column abstract

Tags: titles, abstract

I would like to have my document text start on the same page as my title and abstract, but have the text be in two columns while the abstract spans both columns above the text. I've gotten the text onto the title page ([this old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164700/title-abstract-and-text-beginning-on-same-page/164711#164711) was very helpful and is a nominal duplicate of my question- however, the answers aren't geared for a two-column format), but I can't make the abstract span both columns. This is the format I'm currently following:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{Title}
\author{Authors}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract text
\end{abstract}

\section{The First Section}
Section text...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28110/120578

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B Probabily this question could be closed.