# \vfill does't work after upgrading texmaker

Tags: spacing, multicol

I recently upgrade MikTex and TexMaker to the latest version (2.9.5840 and 4.5 respectively) for another reason. 
the problem is that the command `\null \vfill` before and after column content won't work as the old version
I got this in the new version :
[image]

but a want the result to be as a got in the old version :

[image]

I don't know where the problem is because i didn't change anything in the code

thank's for all !

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) This has nothing to do with texmaker as it has nothing to do with the compilation of your document other than starting LaTeX. (3) As long as we do not know anything about your document we cannot help, giving us images does not help much

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You mean `\null\vfill` (with `f`), right?! (would be the typo in your document also?). Would [How do I force a column-break in a two-column document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10760/64454) help you? Anyway, the best way to help us help you is to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)!

Comment: Yep, I'm talking about the `\vfill` comman, here is my code : 

`\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\clearpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
\vfill \null 
\subsubsection{Vitesse du Vent}
bla bla bla ......
\vfill \null 
\columnbreak
\null \vfill
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{SatelliteWindSpeedAnalyse.jpeg}
\caption{blablalbalbalaba ...... }
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\null \vfill
\end{multicols}
\clearpage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\null
\vfill
\subsubsection{Vitesse du Vent}
\lipsum[1]
\vfill
\null
\columnbreak

\rule{4cm}{0.8\textheight}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

As mentioned by egreg in a comment it would be better to use LaTeX-commands instead of the low-level \null. (But he is not right, that a \vfill at the end is enough, one needs `\vspace*{\fill}` there too.)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\vspace*{\fill}
\subsubsection{Vitesse du Vent}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace*{\fill}
\columnbreak

\rule{4cm}{0.8\textheight}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks !! the problem was just that we should use `\null \vfill` before the text and `\vfill \null` after the text , not  `\null \vfill` before and after ....
thank you very much !

Comment: @BenallalMohamedAnis Actually you should use *neither* `\null\vfill` nor `\vfill\null`. The former should be `\vspace*{\fill}`, the latter can simply be `\vfill`.

Answer (score 2):

Last year I fixed the incorrect handling of vertical space at the end of columns: a space there should get removed unless it is explicitly requested which wasn't the case in all circumstances. From the changelog:

```
2015-03-31 Frank Mittelbach  <Frank.Mittelbach@latex-project.org>

    * multicol.dtx: Another rewrite of \remove@discardable@items to
    capture the case of \vspace (remove) and \vspace* (keep) correctly

2015-03-23  Frank Mittelbach  <latex-bugs@latex-project.org>

    * multicol.dtx: Detect when columns get too large during balancing
    because the user requested more forced breaks than available
    columns.

    Fixed the logic for removing excess white space at column bottoms
    (this is a source of trouble for sure)
```

So in the past `\null\vfill` at the end may have survived, while it would have been correct to remove the `\vfill`. These days it is removed. Moving the box after the fill at this point hides it so it stays.

However, as pointed out, the correct LaTeX command would be `\vsapce*{\fill}` --- that works correctly above and below.