# How to make a section header span the whole page in a twocolumn document

Tags: sectioning, two-column

I am writing a book in twocolumn format. Section headers appear in their respective column, and for most of the book, that is fine for me.

But for a specific chapter of the book, I would prefer the section header to span *both* columns. Only the section header, not the subsection headers, and only in that specific chapter of the book.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: [multicol](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf) package may help you.

Comment: @xport: I've read about the multicol package, and that it is more flexible in this way, but I also read that the multicol environment isn't really meant to render a whole document in columns. The book is somewhat extensive / complex... are you serious about that suggestion? (Best make it an answer so I could vote for it...)

Comment: [How to force column break in multicol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/how-do-i-force-a-column-break-in-a-multi-column-page/8687#8687) answer may help you too. Don't forget to up vote if you are satisfied with it. :-)

Comment: I cannot repost my answer because a link is NOT regarded as an answer by SE/SO policy, so I put in comments. :-)

Comment: You can use `multicols` environment as many as you want in the document.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if it starts on a new page use the optional argument of `\twocolumn`

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[\section{I can find a tool to convert PDF to 
  EPS in my neither bathroom nor kitchen}]

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{bar}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! This is what I've been looking for (but obviously not hard enough).

Comment: @Dev: Are you sure that each section in your document starts on a new page? :-)

Comment: @xport: No, but all of them that I need to stretch across columns. ;-) Besides, I've been doing some testing of your `multicol` suggestion, and it somewhat messes up my column layout. Herbert's suggestion worked perfectly right out-of-the-box. Sorry. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Herbert's answer with `\twocolumn[...]` makes each section starts on a new page. If you don't like this behavior, then use `multicol` package that is very flexible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\title{Introduction to \LaTeX}
\author{xport}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{I can find a tool to convert PDF to EPS in my neither bathroom nor kitchen. Normal mode.}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{multicols}

\section{Jesus is the absolute expression of perfection. With column break.}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\columnbreak
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{multicols}

\section{Jesus is the absolute expression of perfection. Filling from left to right column.}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{multicols*}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

### Notes:

1. Use `\raggedcolumns` globally in the preamble if you don't want the
   bottom baselines of all columns to be aligned. The default is
   `\flushcolumns`, so TEX will normally try to make both the top and
   bottom baselines of all columns align.

Comment: I just scared my coworkers with a guffaw when I realized there's actually a *package* for lorem ipsum... :-D

Comment: Try load `blindtext` package and use `\blindtext` or `Blinddocument` in your body.