# Macro or package for typesetting "LaTeX" (the name)?

Tags: macros, packages, logos

I [just realized](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23767) there's a LaTeX package for printing the text of "lorem ipsum".

*Surely* then, there's also a macro / package for writing "LaTeX" (with the proper super-/subscript) in a document.

But I found googling for this a bit hard. ("LaTeX macro"? Probably not.)

Can any of you groks help me out here?

Comment: It's simply `\LaTeX`. You don't need a package for this. See [How to write (La)TeX (with braces) or any other TeX-related logo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-braces-or-any-other-tex-related-logo)

Comment: I'd add here that some people (including me) feel that using a logo in running text is not a great idea. Thus I favour just 'LaTeX' (Really, even this is a bit questionable, and 'Latex' would be been the best choice. However, that is a battle long-lost.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The command `\LaTeX` should produce what you want. You'd probably want to add a `\<space>` after it if used inside a sentence.

Comment: /facepalm... somewhat obvious, is it? I actually tried `\latex` but didn't think to use the upper-/lowercase (since I was under the impression that LaTeX commands are always lowercase)... Thanks!

Answer (score 53):

This is covered in many tutorials like [lshort](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort). But here's a more complete list:

- `\LaTeX` typesets the LaTeX logo
- `\LaTeXe` typesets the LaTeX2e logo
- `\TeX` typesets the original TeX logo. You can often use it to obtain other TeX-based logos.
- `\AmSTeX`, `\BibTeX`, `\SliTeX` and `\PlainTeX` typeset what their names say. These are defined in the [`doc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/doc) package.
- `\XeTeX`, `\XeLaTeX`, `\LuaTeX` and `\LuaLaTeX` can be obtained with the [`metalogo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/metalogo) package
- e-TeX and some other logos are available in package [`hologo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hologo)
- Finally, you can get the METAFONT logo with the package [`mflogo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mflogo)

The `metalogo` package also allows you to customize the appearance of `\TeX`, `\LaTeX`, `\LaTeXe`, `\XeTeX`, `\XeLaTeX`, `\LuaTeX` and `\LuaLaTeX` logos, which is useful if you use a font other than Computer Modern.

See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-logos.

Comment: Herbert has enumerated [the complete list of logos here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/how-to-write-latex-with-braces-or-any-other-tex-related-logo/11097#11097)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the `gmutils` package contains some improvements: not only logos typeset using that package work better with non-CM fonts, but it also defines a `\DeclareLogo` command, which takes care of logos in PDF bookmarks.