# Add LaTeX with version number to LaTeX document

Tags: logos

I love that in LaTeX it is possible to stylize the name of the language by typing `\LaTeX`, and I noticed on wikipedia that the proper way to stylize LaTeX2e is as follows:

[image: LaTeX2e Stylized]

Is there a simple way to add this stylized latex version number to a document?

Thanks!

Comment: See in particular [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23776/119) on the linked duplicate.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers the correct command is \LaTeXe