# Making section headers break two column flow

Tags: sectioning, two-column

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm writing a document for which I'm using `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`. Is it possible to make `\section` headers break the two column flow? To clarify, I'd like a long section title to continue into the space normally occupied by the second column, and the two-column flow would continue below the `\section` header.

I think I've read about doing this with minipages, but I'd rather not complicate the markup in-line. A preamble solution would be vastly preferable.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23767/21591) might be helpful.

Comment: Did you try the solution to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23767/how-to-make-a-section-header-span-the-whole-page-in-a-twocolumn-document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the `multicol` package for this purpose and not the `twocolumn` option.

In your preamble:

```
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}
```

And in the document:

```
\section{Long section name}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Your very long text
\end{multicols}

\section{Another long section name}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Your very long text
\end{multicols}
```

For details on the `multicol` package and all those customizing options, see http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf

You could also use the `multicol` for having 3 (or even more) columns:

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
This goes in three columns
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{5}
This goes in five columns
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of our site.

Comment: This works, thanks. Oops - just read the guide - am I not supposed to leave thank you messages?