# Define section title span in preamble for KOMA twocolumn scrbook

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, two-column, multicolumn, scrbook

I put multiple short sections together to a book. I want a two column layout, but a new section should always span both columns. The sections are generated from markdown files with pandoc.

I tried [@xports approach with `\multicol`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23769/239260), but I do not want to edit each section title and would prefer to define the behavior in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed in a comment by @esdd I used a hook for the headings with cuted and needspace:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{cuted, needspace}
\newcommand*{\startonecolumn}[1]{\begin{strip}\needspace{4\baselineskip}}
\newcommand*{\stoponecolumn}[1]{\end{strip}}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/section}{\startonecolumn}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}{\stoponecolumn}
% \AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/subsection}{\startonecolumn}
% \AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/subsection}{\stoponecolumn}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

I also added the hooks for spanning subsections (commented out above).

[image: mwe output page 1]

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You could make use of the `cuted` package like in the following example. It may be possible, I think, that LaTeX doesn't always prevent page breaks between the section title and the following paragraph. Maybe some adjustment is needed.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum, cuted}

\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
\begin{strip}\thesection\autodot\enskip #4\end{strip}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[3-6]

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

First page of the output:

[image]

---

*Edit:* If you don't want to use the same styling for subsection headings, you can use the following to apply the above settings only to sections. I also changed the code so that the starred version of section title won't get a section number:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum, cuted}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
\Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
\begin{strip}\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}\end{strip}%
}{%
\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}%
}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

The first page of the output renders like this:

[image]

Comment: Your redefinition of `\sectionlinesformat` gives unexpected results for e.g. subsection headings or unnumbered sections headings, because the section number would be used for them, too. Additionally environment `strip` would be used for e.g. subsections, too.

Comment: @esdd You are right. See my edit. You then need to restrict the re-formatting so that it only applies to section headers. I am not sure why the spacing sometimes seems to be a bit off, though.

Comment: Why you do not use the original definition for the `section` level in environment `strip`, i.e. `\begin{strip}\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{#4}\end{strip}`?

Comment: You can load package `needspace`. And you could use the hooks for the headings provided by the class `scrbook`: `\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/section}{\startonecolumn}` and `\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}{\stoponecolumn}` with `\newcommand*{\startonecolumn}[1]{\begin{strip}\needspace{4\baselineskip}}` and `\newcommand*{\stoponecolumn}[1]{\end{strip}}`.

Comment: @esdd|s solution works great and is really beautiful! I have some issues with spacing and column breaking, but I assume this is due to my short sections with lots of lists.

Comment: Any ideas, how to prevent section headings separating from the section?

Comment: I think @esdd's solution is indeed great and they should post it as an answer! But @orangerkater is right: somehow, neither `\nopagebreak` nor `\needspace` can really prevent the headings from being seperated in certain situations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that will work for your MWE.

```
% sectionprob.tex  SE 591865
%\documentclass[twocolumn=true]{scrbook}
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% \section not in multicolumn
\let\savesection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  \end{multicols}
  \savesection{#1}
  \begin{multicols}{2}}

% \chapter not in multicolumn
\let\savechapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{%
  \end{multicols}
  \savechapter{#1}
  \begin{multicols}{2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}  % start 2 columns
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[3-4]

\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{multicols} % end 2 columns
\end{document}
```

[image]

Strangely to me regular `\chapter` in a 2 column multicolumn gets set above the second column.

Comment: Your redefinition of `\chapter` and `\section` breaks, if their starred version or the optional argument would be used. `\tableofcontents` can not be used.

Comment: @esdd My solution works for the given MWE. I admit that It will not work for starred versions or those with optional parameters but the OP gave no indication that they might be used. I felt that I had spent enough time on this without going into all possible (but possibly unused) versions. --- GOM