# Force column break within tabbing environment

Tags: page-breaking, multicol, tabbing

Basically following the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/how-do-i-force-a-column-break-in-a-multi-column-page), I'm trying to enfore a column break in my text. My text is, however, embedded within a `tabbing` environment, and following the said instructions results in the following error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.20 {\vfill
            }
?
```

Here's a minimally (not) working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large{\textbf{My title.}}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tabbing}
Here \= is \= a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
\vfill
\columnbreak
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
\end{tabbing}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large{\textbf{My title.}}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tabbing}
Here \= is \= a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\[\fill\columnbreak]
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
\end{tabbing}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting trick.  But why does it work?

Comment: @A.Ellett you can't add `\vfill` or `\columnbreak` after `\\ ` as in the MWE as the horizontal mode cell has already been started, `\\[\fill]` would be standard latex way of adding fill glue at that point and since it just translates internally to `end row\vskip\fill start next row` It's only mild abuse to place other vertical mode commands after the fill and get `end row\vskip\fill \columnbreak start next row`

Comment: I appreciate you explaining that.

Answer (score 2):

You could terminate the `tabbing` environment and re-establish the tab alignments in the subsequent column, together with `\kill` to remove the tab definitions:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large{\textbf{My title.}}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tabbing}
Here \= is \= a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word\\
Here \> is \> a sentence\\
Here \> is \> a word
\end{tabbing}
\vfill
\columnbreak
\begin{tabbing}
Here \= is \= a sentence \kill% Re-establish tab positions
Here \> is \> a word\\
\end{tabbing}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `\kill` supposed to re-establish the tab positions from the first column? In my case it doesn't.

Comment: @Sverre: Note that I've used `\=` to re-establish the tab positions. `\kill` just removes the line so that it isn't set/visible.