# Forcing separation of content in two columns

Tags: two-column, multicol

I've been using the `multicol` package lately because I was trying to typeset content in two columns and I like minimalist solutions.

However I've been having trouble trying to force content to stay in one of the two columns only. But I've seen this behavior occurring:

- *If the left column is shorter than a page*, using `\columnbreak` is enough and it will force the rest of the content to the right column. For example: [How do I force a column-break in a multi-column page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8683/4778)
- *If the content is longer than a page*, though, using this command won't bring any results (except for the last page/part of the content). The command is ignored, and the first column will use the second until the first condition is satisfied again, i.e. the content is shorter than a page.

How can I force the content to stick to the first (left) column until `\columnbreak` (or a similar command) is issued and only then start at the top of the second column? Or am I using the wrong package for this sort of task?

Comment: If you use `multicolumn` you want the `*` form so it doesn't balance the columns, but that is the main point of the package, for what you describe you would be better with the standard `[twocolumn]` option.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I've seen that package being mentioned before but I can't find a page or documentation for it. Do you mind writing a very short example of how to use that package as an answer?

Comment: I meant don't use a package at all, just use the standard twocolumn system built into latex. `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah I see, but wouldn't that divide my whole document into two columns? I only need this for parts of text.

Comment: use `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` commands to switch

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How/where do I switch? Sorry, I never used this command.

Comment: Are you saying that you want your text indefinitely in the first column until you issue a command like `\columnbreak`?

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes!

Comment: Try the [`paracol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) package. The needed environment is `\begin{paracol}{2}...\end{paracol}` and the command you are looking for is `\switchcolumn`.

Comment: @karlkoeller Perfect! Do you mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the [`paracol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) package.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin]{babel}  %only for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}        %only for the example

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

  \lipsum[1-2]

  \lipsum[1-2]

  \switchcolumn

  \lipsum[1-2]

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You might also take a look at the CTAN topic [`parallel`](http://www.ctan.org/topic/parallel) where you can find similar packages.

Comment: @Alenanno you're welcome. Happy to help.