# Multi column layout

Tags: multicolumn

I have been using LaTex for isolated mathematical expressions, so I'm quite a newbie in the text layout questions.

Here's the layout i'm trying to achieve:
[image]

The gray outline boxes are shown just for the clarity, there should be no borders in the resulting render. So, the width of the page is split in 6 columns, and the 1st and 6th have titles. And the content in each column is controlled, no dynamic flow of text into the next column is allowed. So maybe I am looking for table layout rather than column layout.

Here's my lame attempt to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{vwcol} 

\begin{document}
\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.8,0.2},sep=1.2cm,justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=1em]
  \noindent
  \normalsize{\underline{\textbf{Part A}}}
  \newpage
  \noindent
  \normalsize{\underline{\textbf{Part B}}}
\end{vwcol}

\begin{vwcol}[widths={0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2},sep=.3cm,justify=flush,rule=0pt,indent=1em]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
    \item four
    \item five
  \end{enumerate}
  \newpage
  \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{6}
    \item six
    \item seven
    \item eight
    \item nine
    \item ten
  \end{enumerate}
  \newpage
  more
  \newpage
  more
\end{vwcol}
\end{document}
```

This is rendered very weird, with only four items visible in the first column, and the fifth item at far right side. The other column content is not visible.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could use [\usepackage{multicol}](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=de). `\begin{multicols}{6}
  \begin{enumerate}  \item
  \item
  \item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}`

Comment: For the header maybe [How do I force a column-break in a multi-column page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/how-do-i-force-a-column-break-in-a-multi-column-page) could be useful: `\begin{multicols}{6}
A \vfill\null\columnbreak  B \vfill\null\columnbreak C \vfill\null\columnbreak D \vfill\null\columnbreak  E \vfill\null\columnbreak F \vfill\null\columnbreak
  \begin{enumerate}...`

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by using two sets of multicols{6}, one for the titles and the other for the numbered lists.