# How to force to start to write in the right column in a twocolumn document

Tags: two-column

If I want to start to write in the right column of the document in a twocolumn document class how should I do?

I have already tried

```
 \newpage
```

but it startss new page

and

```
 \columnbreak
```

results not defined.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8687/156344

Comment: Thank you for your answer but actually this doesn't work. I have already tried but infact it seems to work only with the multicol package.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "related". Btw, you can always use `multicols`.

Comment: Yes I know, I have jus pointed it out, by the way I have already wrote a long document so I am not willing to switch to the multicolumn package now.

Comment: I don't think it is that complicated. You only have to add a `\usepackage` line, and a pair of `\begin{multicols}{2}` `\end{multicols}` to the beginning and the end of your document...

Answer (score 2):

Try this (less any of my typos):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}  % empty space for first column
\newpage % start next column
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any of a number of invisible items can be used, including `\leavevmode`, `\null`, `\strut`, and `\hrule height0pt` (which I like to think of as a horizontal `\strut`).